# visdom.server inside Docker

Tags: python, docker

I am running a pytorch training on [CycleGan](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix) inside a Docker image.

I want to use [visdom](https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom) to show the progress of the training (also recommended from the CycleGan project).

I can start a `visdom.server` inside the docker container and access it outside of the container. But when I try to use the [basic example](https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom#python-example) on `visdom` inside a `bash` session, of the same container that is running the `visdom.server`. I get connection refused errors such as `The requested URL could not be retrieved`.

I think I need to configure the `visdom.Visdom()` in the example in some custom way to be able to send the data to the server.

Thankful for any help!

#### Notes

- When I start `visdom.server` it says `You can navigate to http://c4b7a2be26c4:8097`, when all the examples mentions `localhost:8097`.
- I am trying to do this behind a proxy.
- I realised that, in order to curl `localhost:8097`, I need to use `curl --noproxy localhost, localhost:8097`. So I will have to do something similar inside `visdom`.

Answer (score 3):

When setting `http_proxy` inside a docker container, you need to set `no_proxy=localhost, 127.0.0.1` as well in order to allow connections to local host.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more what this means? Does setting the `http_proxy` go in the `Dockerfile` or in the `docker run` command?

Comment: As far as I remember, it could go into either.

But the modern way is probably to configure the Docker client itself, see the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, And I found when you use a docker container to connect server, then you can not use the same docker container to run you code